# Delete specified type of file over subdirectories (Python)

Tags: python

i have a lot of directories and subdirectories and in almost all of them I have a type of file (.psd and .ttf) that I want to delete. I tried to make a script using os.walk module but it's more difficult than I thought. Is there any other methods I could use? Thanks

```
import os  
def check_extension(fname,ext):  
    return fname.endswith(ext)  


for root_path,dirs,files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):  
    for fname in files:  
        if check_extension(fname,'psd'):  
            os.remove(fname)
```

Comment: Please show us the script you attempted to write, including tracebacks / exceptions, errors, or even just expected output / results vs actual output / results so we can help further.

Comment: Sorry, it got cut off when i posted it, edited.

Comment: This'd be a better task for `find`: `find . -type f -name "*.psd" -or -name "*.tif" -delete`

Comment: @user3501165: Just replace `os.remove(fname)` with `os.remove(os.path.join(root_path, fname))` and your script should work.

Comment: @Blender that's it! Thank you, I was struggling about how to get the complete path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code long time ago, it should do the job:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_extensions(folders, ext):
    '''Returns a list of all files that are stored in folders and their subdirectories with extension in ext'''
    found=[]
    while folders:
        temp=[]
        for folder in folders:
             try:
                 temp+=get_items(folder,None,False)
                 found+=get_items(folder,ext,True)
             except WindowsError:
                 pass
        folders=temp
    return found

def get_items(directory,ext,files=True):
    if files:
        return [join(directory,f) for f in listdir(directory) if (isfile(join(directory,f)) and f.split('.')[-1] in ext)]
    return [join(directory,f) for f in listdir(directory) if not isfile(join(directory,f))]
```

Usage:

```
import os

for file in get_extensions([List of your folders], ['psd', 'ttf']):
    os.remove(file)
```